# Setting input values to null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, ionic-framework

I wolud like to set input values to null after clicked on button. After clicked button function spremi() does what it does, but i wish to set values of podaci.tezina and podaci.mamac to starting values, so user can enter new values.

```
 .controller('SpremiCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $ionicPopup, $location, $window) {


    $scope.ribe = ["Saran", "Stuka", "Som"];

    var ribice = [];

    $scope.spremi = function(t_tezina, m_mamac){

          console.log(t_tezina);
          console.log(m_mamac);
          var podaci = {Tezina: t_tezina, Mamac: m_mamac};  
          console.log(podaci);
          ribice.push(podaci);

          $localStorage.fish = ribice;
          console.log(ribice);

    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Spremljeno'

         });
       };

 html

<ion-view view-title="Browse">
      <ion-content>
      <select id="vrstaribe" ng-model="selekt" ng-options="r as r for r in ribe" selected>
       <option value="">Vrsta ribe</option> 
      </select>
       <label class="item item-input">
       <input id="tezina" type="number" placeholder="Tezina" ng-model="podaci.tezina">
       </label>
       <label class="item item-input">
       <input id="mamac" type="text" placeholder="Mamac" ng-model="podaci.mamac">
       </label>
       <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="spremi(podaci.tezina, podaci.mamac)">Spremi</button>
       <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="dohvati()">Prikaži</button>
       <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="isprazni()">Isprazni</button>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: Have you tried to  reset the values at the end of the method? `podaci.Tezina = ''`

Comment: Try this  podaci.tezina=null and podaci.mamac=""; at the end of spremi function.

Comment: ok, that do it, seeting values to " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the values at the end of your method, after all other logic, so that it is fresh for the next call.

```
$scope.spremi = function(t_tezina, m_mamac){
    console.log(t_tezina);
    console.log(m_mamac);
    var podaci = {Tezina: t_tezina, Mamac: m_mamac};  
    console.log(podaci);
    ribice.push(podaci);

    $localStorage.fish = ribice;
    console.log(ribice);

    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Spremljeno'
    });


    // reset your variables here.
    podaci.Tezina = '';
    podaci.Mamac = '';
};
```

It should also be noted that you should use `$log.debug()` (or friends) rather than `console.log()`, since you can inform the `$logProvider` to disable debug output when you are building for a release, rather than debugging. That can make life a bit easier.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'm new with angular so i have this begginers mistakes

Comment: No, it is not a mistake, just that things are different in angularjs. Here is a [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) which has some great input on styling and practices. I highly recommend it.